# WPF negative margins are not displayed correctly

Tags: wpf

I am trying to simulate a tab control with a nice TabHeader and TabContent. The control should look something like this:

[image: desired header border]

This is achieved by setting the `Margin' of the first Header - "HOME" to Margin="2 0 2 -1".

**ISSUE:** if I re-size the window to a certain smaller width, the header item visually clips its content. Here is the result:

[image: undesired border]

I really would like to know why this is happening and how ca i avoid this.

The sample xaml to prove the problem:

```
<Window 
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="550" Width="525">
<Grid Margin="0 50">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <Border  BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="Black" Grid.Row="1"/>

    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Grid.Row="0">
        <Border Width="50" Margin="2 0 2 -1" BorderThickness="1 1 1 0" BorderBrush="Black" Background="White">
            <TextBlock Text="HOME" />
        </Border>
        <Border Width="150" Margin="2 -20" Height="20" BorderThickness="1 1 1 0" >
            <TextBlock Text="EDIT" />
        </Border>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Some ideas that come up to mind:
 1. No snapping to device pixels.
 2. Border is rendered after StackPanel, and thus it has higher z-order.
 3. StackPanel drawing area doesn't get invalidated, and thus it doesn't get redrawn.
Would like to know the answer myself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you resize the window, XAML renderer redraw any flexible (still can be resized or moved relatively). when you reach the StackPanel  width limit (limited by what it contains or a fixed Width) the control is ignored at redrawing (even what it contains) and the renderer keeps redrawing other flexible controls; in your case : the first border. that's why comes suddenly on the top of the others.

Moving the margin to the StackPanel will do the trick :

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Grid.Row="0" Margin="2 0 2 -1">
            <Border Width="50"  BorderThickness="1 1 1 0" BorderBrush="Black" Background="White">
                <TextBlock Text="HOME" />
            </Border>
            <Border Width="150" Height="20" BorderThickness="1 1 1 0" >
                <TextBlock Text="EDIT" />
            </Border>
        </StackPanel>
```

Comment: The modification you made makes the Horizontal `StackPanel` less than minimum window size and you can not reproduce the issue anymore but it's still there. Just make the header text a little bit longer. +1 for trying to help.

Comment: d'oh, you beat me to it!  But I don't buy your explanation.  The WPF compositor should be preserving the z-order of the elements, regardless of which ones need to be invalidated.  It appears to be more than a simple z-ordering issue: take the original code and set the `BorderBrush` on the second tab, then observe how the top border of the second tab gets clipped, despite not being occluded and `ClipToBounds` not being set anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution with 2 columns

```
   <Grid Margin="0,50">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="auto" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <Border Grid.ColumnSpan="2"  BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="Black" Grid.Row="1" />

    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Grid.Row="0">
        <Border Width="50" Margin="2,0,2,-1" BorderThickness="1,1,1,0" BorderBrush="Black" Background="White">
            <TextBlock Text="HOME" />
        </Border>
        <Border Width="50" Margin="2" Height="20" BorderThickness="1,1,1,0" >
            <TextBlock Text="EDIT" />
        </Border>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

This makes the grid not get clipped by the window size.

EDIT added additional column to push the border to the edge.

Cheers,
Eric

Comment: I can not afford to lose the option to stretch the control's to all available horizontal space. Can not use your solution, but it works.

Comment: I modified my solution to extend the content area to stretch horizontally.

Answer (score 0):

I would theorize that this is an oddity in the layout code of `StackPanel`.  You should be able to work around it by moving the negative margin to the `StackPanel` itself, as opposed to the tabs within:

```
<Grid Margin="0 50" UseLayoutRounding="True">
  <Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <RowDefinition Height="auto" />
    <RowDefinition Height="*" />
  </Grid.RowDefinitions>

  <Border BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="#7FFF0000" Grid.Row="1" />
  <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Grid.Row="0" Margin="0,0,0,-1">
    <Border Width="50" Margin="2 0 2 0" BorderThickness="1 1 1 0" BorderBrush="Lime" Background="Yellow">
      <TextBlock Text="HOME" />
    </Border>
    <Border Width="150" Margin="2 0 2 0" Height="20" BorderBrush="Blue" BorderThickness="1 1 1 0" Background="Yellow">
      <TextBlock Text="EDIT" />
    </Border>
  </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

Note that I changed the colors to assist with visual debugging.  It's a useful technique, but you'll probably want to change them back :).